# Probability of Throwing Even Number of Sixes

Tags: probability

My question is whether there is an intuitive explanation for why, when a fair die is thrown $n$ times, the probability of getting an even number of sixes equals $$\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\right).$$

I already proved this using induction, so any other approach would be helpful.

Comment: Well...recursively, if $p_n$ is the answer for $n$ tosses, we have $p_n=\frac 56 p_{n-1}+\frac 16(1-p_{n-1})$ though I imagine that's more or less the same as your inductive proof.

Comment: To clarify: I think @J Dijkstra is asking for the conditional probability: i.e find the probability an even number of sixes is rolled GIVEN that at least one of the dice rolls a 6.

Comment: @TobyMak  Why do you think that?  If $n=0$ then I'd say $p_0=1$ as you certainly get $0$ sixes and $0$ is even.  The OP's formula gives $1$ as desired.  Similarly the formula correctly gives $p_1=\frac 56$ though your interpretation would yield $0$.

Comment: Then is the OP referring to conditional or regular probability?

Comment: @Tobmak I'm referring to regular probability. I proved it with Bayes' theorem like lulu mentioned.